# Nouns constructed out of an adjective and a suffix?

Tags: hyphenation, internet

I experienced a bit of interesting language-building this past weekend. A post about "subtle -isms" (i.e. subtle sexism, subtle racism, etc.) had various commenters who used the phrase "subtle-ism" (no space), and even one person who used "subtleism" as a noun on twitter:

"... 'subtleism' = lowlevel *-ism that hurts in aggregate"

Obviously "subtleism" is a long way from being a "real word", but I do think it has a very interesting and unintuitive construction: subtle (adj.) + -ism (suffix) -> subtleism (noun).

I'm wondering if there are any other words constructed similarly (through rebracketing, de-hyphenation, etc) in the English Language.

Edit: I don't think "subtleism" is a particularly well-constructed or intuitive word, but someone did use it and I'm interested in seeing if there are any similar words. Thanks!

Comment: Nounizing other parts of speech and Verbizing nouns and other parts of speech is the bedrock of modern day word coining.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for “any” such words, which makes it a list-question, something which is off-topic on all SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of *(adj.)-ism* nouns in English (as well as other in languages):
**existentialism**, **expressivism**, **intellectualism**, **moralism**, **nationalism**, **parallelism**.

I particularly liked **masculinism** and **incendiarism**. ;)

Edit: Found two other funny ones: **prettyism** and **reliabilism**.

Source: [English words suffixed with -ism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ism)